# Promise inside forEach loop within promise, bad firebase database design?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im bulding a shopping cart with Firebase, when a user have paid a function triggers and I get all the items from the cart then I create and array of products Id's (pids) after that, I want to search the store ID of each item to notify them.

The store ID is a child in the product node.
Products->{pid}->sid

This is how I do after getting the pids

```
.then(snap => {
        return pids.forEach( pids => {
            productIdRef = root.child(`/products/${pids}`);
             //Here I should create a promise to get the Stores Ids:
             // productIdRef.once("value")....
        });
```

That is nesting promises and as far as I know is not good.

So is there something I could do to avoid nesting promises or is this doomed from the beginning due to a bad Firebase database design?

Update: complete function:

```
    var itemsRef = NOTIFICATION_SNAPSHOT.adminRef.parent.child('items');
    var pids = [];
    return itemsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
         pids.push(childSnapshot.key);
        });

    }).then(snap => {
        return pids.forEach(pids => {
            productIdRef= root.child(`/products/${pids}`).once('value');

        });

    }).catch(error => {
        // Something went wrong.
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: I don't see what you've done with your promises here, and I'm not sure what you mean by "nested".  Could you show what you've done more completely?

Comment: What makes you think nesting promises is not good? Do you consider nesting loops to be bad as well?

Comment: I know this is not relevant but I suggest using well established SQL for shopping cart purposes. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of references to maintain.

Comment: @Bergi I assume nesting promises is not good because I get a warning from Eslint, if you are sure is not a problem then I could ignore this warning

Comment: Ohh thanks for the suggestion @user1027620, I though it could be the same on firebase.

Comment: @Gaspar I don't know what your actual code is and what the warning says specifically. When you can avoid nesting you should usually go for the simpler solution, but ESlint rules often don't understand when something is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by nested

Perhaps use `Promise.all` like below:

```
.then(snap => {
    return Promise.all(pids.map(pid => {
        return root.child(`/products/${pid}`);
    }));
}).then((storeIds) => {
    // result of root.child()
});
```

Comment: I have never use .maps before so let me read some documentation to see what you have done there jeje.

Comment: ```map``` is a way to transform an array into another, in this case, transforming array of product ids into an array of Promises, [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) Along with map, you may also want to look up [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)